# Close browser tab using JavaScript/jQuery event

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have a logout button on which if user clicks, browser tab need to be closed. I have tried with the following method:

```
window.close();
```

but its not working in any of the browsers.

Comment: I don't think, this would be possible. If you really want to close tab ( window ). Open your website in a separate window with `window.open`

Comment: check these links,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166936/close-aspx-using-javascript-jquery/28167044#28167044

Answer (score 2):

If you try to close any window with `window.close()` you will get error message like

`"Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script"` (Message Depends on Browser)

so, its mean you must have to open windows by JavaScript first to close by your code, like:

`window.open("http://www.google.com/");`

now you can easily close this window by `window.close()`.

.

Another advantage using this functionality is you can also close `Child Window` from

Parent Windows`. like:

```
var win;
$('#click').click(function() {
    win = window.open("test3.html", "something", "width=550,height=170");
});

function closeit() {
    win.close();
}
```