# close .aspx using JavaScript/ Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have searched this issue on other links like 
 [window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)  etc. but couldn't able to solve it
I want to close a page using below code, but it's not working on any browser.

my url is like :

> http://server/solutionName/Confirmation.aspx

**Warning** :

> Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

**HTML**:

```
 <img alt="Close" src="images/close.png" onclick="return confirm_delete();">
```

**Script**:

```
  function confirm_delete()
   {
      if (confirm("Are you sure you want to close?") == true)
          window.close();

      else
          return false;
    }
```

Here is the screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: What is the problem with that code?

Comment: I think(I may be wrong cause things change day after day) in some browsers you can't close a window with JavaScript, unless it were open using JavaScript

Comment: How are you opening the `Confirmation.aspx`.

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ: through wizard. on next button click. it's the last page of wizard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following lines of code

```
        var Browser = navigator.appName;
        var indexB = Browser.indexOf('Explorer');
        if (indexB > 0) {

            var indexV = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') + 5;
            var Version = navigator.userAgent.substring(indexV, indexV + 1);

            if (Version >= 7) {
                window.open('', '_self', '');
                window.close();
            }
            else if (Version == 6) {
                window.opener = null;
                window.close();
            }
            else {
                window.opener = '';
                window.close();
            }
        }
        else {
            window.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The hacky workarounds for Chrome (reopen window inside itself and close it):

```
<script>
    open(location, '_self').close();
</script>
```

This code works in my Chrome:

```
<script>

function confirm_delete()
{
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to close?") == true) open(location, '_self').close();
    else return false;
} 
confirm_delete();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> `window.close` When this method is called, the referenced window is closed.
>
> This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened
>   by a script using the window.open() method. If the window was not
>   opened by a script, the following error appears in the JavaScript
>   Console: Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.close

Comment: then how can i close an aspx page on a button ?

Comment: If you want to redirect user to close the current page and open another one....tell the server. :)  or, you can open the child window from script and then close it with script :)